# Why doesn't this image render in IE8?

Tags: image, nginx, internet-explorer-8

I've got a few images that appear "broken" (with a red letter X) when served via nginx to IE8.

I can see this independent of the webpage and when I navigate a simulator directly to the image resource: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/aa8341f932cd0ed050e8b3e2aaea9db44ee83f0d

Why doesn't this image render in IE8?

http://admin.mtdemocrat.com/ads/20150204/17084.jpg

Here is a the meta data for this image

[image]

Comment: you get that problem only on IE or also on other Browsers like Google Chrome?

Comment: See the referenced screenshots. Only IE8, not IE9, and in the image set Chrome and Safari are working http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/aa8341f932cd0ed050e8b3e2aaea9db44ee83f0d